# Reading a text file with floats fast

Tags: c++, performance, parsing, c++11

I have a text file with ~4 mio floats, i.e 30MB, and I want to read them into a `vector<float>`.

The code I have is very bare bone, and gets the job done

```
std::fstream is("data.txt", std::ios_base::in);

float number;
while (is >> number)
{
   //printf("%f ", number);
   number_vec.push_back(number);
}
```

The problem is that it takes 20-30 s on a modern desktop workstation. At first I assumed I did something stupid, but the more I starred at the code, the more I started accepting that maybe it was just the time it takes to parse all those ascii float values into `floats`

However, then I remembered that Matlab can read, and parse, the same file almost instantly (disk speed seems to be the limit), so it is obvious that my code is just very inefficient.

The only thing I could think of was to reserve the required elements in the vector in advance, but it didn't improve the situation at all.

Can someone help me understand why? and maybe help writing a faster solution?

**EDIT** The textfile looks like this:

> 152.00256  45.8569  5.87214  0.225  -0.0005 .....

i.e. One row, space delimited.

Comment: Please post sample of text file.

Comment: you need to use a profiler to pinpoint bottlenecks. beyond that reserving space in the vector ahead of time should provide a significant boost.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fast textfile reading in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925051/fast-textfile-reading-in-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse space-separated floats in C++ quickly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465061/how-to-parse-space-separated-floats-in-c-quickly)

Comment: For an idea on performance see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664272/is-stdvector-so-much-slower-than-plain-arrays

Comment: @BradAllred I'm trying to keep up with all the other comments. But your link does look like the same problem I have. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Tried your code on my system, takes around 1.3s with 4M floating point numbers (72MiB). Are you sure you are measuring an optimized build?

Comment: @BaummitAugen I'm sure. But if you look at Brad Allreds link you can see that fstream is extremly slow on windows compared to maybe fscan. Are you running linux?

Comment: @Markus Yes, so maybe that's it. (Even on Linux, `fscanf` turns out to be ca. 30% faster, but don't sue me if I did not measure this correctly.)

Comment: That's like 3000 cycles/byte, or 20000 cycles/float, which is ridiculous. Try reading the whole thing into a string first; if it's significantly faster then your code is likely not buffering the reads.

Answer (score 0):

please consider taking a look at the possible duplicates shared by @gsamaras and @Brad Allred. Anyway, I will try to reply with a simple answer that will aim on keeping the code simplicity/friendliness and consider the following two premises:

- You have a constraint regarding the file and will neither change the file format, neither the way floats are presented textually in it.
- You want to keep using STL and are not looking for a library specialized/optimized for the challenge you are facing.

With those stated constraints and mindset, my main suggestion would be to preallocate your containers, both the float vector as the internal iostream buffer:

- Increase performance of insertion in **number_vec** by reserving the required size in the std vector. This can be achieved by a call to *reserve* as explained in this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888265/is-it-more-efficient-to-preallocate-a-vector).
- Increase performance of the iostream by setting the buffer size used internally. This can be achieved by a call to *pubsetbuf* as explained in this [other stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166263/how-to-get-iostream-to-perform-better).

Comment: copying the file to a `std::string` is _not_ likely to improve performance. Using a memory mapped file would be much better.

Comment: Agreed @BradAllred, I will edit end remove the secondary part of my post as it is misleading.